# mysql socket issues

Tags: mysql, socket

Whenever I try and run mysql I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I did some research and it looks to be cause the file mysqld.sock doesn't exist. I did a

```
ps -elf | grep mysql
```

and could not find mysql running. I then did

```
service mysql start
```

and it just froze (never started) I eventually ^C out of it and did

```
service mysql status
```

and it said that mysql is running, but when I run

```
ps -elf | grep mysql
```

it again shows nothing. I then stop the mysql service and again it hangsup so I used ^C to stop that and when I check the status it properly shows the status as stopped. I am so awkwardly lost and don't know where to go from here. The following is the latest from my error log file:

```
111227 18:07:42 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './wordpress/wp_7_rg_form_view.frm' (errno: 24)
111227 21:37:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

111227 21:37:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
111227 21:37:45  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111227 21:37:48  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 4272160105
111227 21:37:48 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

111227 21:40:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
111227 21:40:33 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
111227 21:40:33  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

The following is (part of) my my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /storageContainer/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
```

Let me know if you need more info... We would theoretically need to get mysql back up and running without losing anydata ...

Side note: I also checked and we only have 1 instance of the mysql-server.

Comment: The errors that you are experiencing are explained in the logs you pasted. Look for "ERROR". The server is not running.

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/143373/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket maybe it can help you

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, I know it's not running, but I can't get it to start running. Whenever I do server mysql start it just hangs forever and never actually starts...

Comment: @JavierConstanzo Didn't really help as in their instance mysql was remaining running throughout the whole process. Mine isn't running at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error lines should help you : MySQL can't open files and then stop before doing something nasty. So check why these files can't be opened. ./wordpress/wp_7_rg_form_view.frm and ./mysql/plugin.frm should exists and be writeable for MySQL. Usualy they are in /var/lib/mysql folder in Linux (In your case /storageContainer/mysql). If they exists, check permissions. 
Do you change something on this server ? If MySQL loose files like this, there is maybe a hardware problem too.

Comment: All the permissions are correct from the looks of it. (all are 644 with the user mysql as the owner)

I don't recall changing something in the server, but it could have been an automated one? I can look into hardware problems too, but we are hosted externally so it might take a little bit of sleuthing.